# I have no connection to server in ActiveMQ Artemis web console

Tags: console, activemq-artemis

I deploy ActiveMQ Artemis but I get no server connection in my web console. The `jolokia-access.xml` shows:

```xml
<restrict>
  <cors>
    <!-- Allow cross origin access from localhost ... -->
    <allow-origin>*</allow-origin>
    <!-- Options from this point on are auto-generated by Create.java from the Artemis CLI -->
    <!-- Check for the proper origin on the server side, too -->
    <strict-checking/>
  </cors>
</restrict>
```

The web binding is:

```xml
<web path="web">
  <binding uri="http://0.0.0.0:8161">
    <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
    <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
    <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
  </binding>
</web>
```

See below the console output and the server logs:

[image]

Comment: Hi Justin - is this a jolokia-access.xml issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a problem with your `etc/jolokia-access.xml` configuration. It's likely that the `allow-origin` is not configured properly. Here's the default configuration:

```xml
<allow-origin>*://localhost*</allow-origin>
```

You should replace `localhost` with whatever hostname or IP address where the broker is actually listening for HTTP connections. You can find that information in `etc/bootstrap.xml`.

For what it's worth, the error in the log has nothing to do with the web console. It is related to the cluster-connection.

Comment: Hi Justin..my jolokia-access.xml shows <allow-origin>*</allow-origin>.... I am using a broker already created so I cannot use --relax jolika which I did use before

Comment: You should modify your original question to include those details.

Comment: Justin - Thank you for advice on Jolokia ..I added service host name:Port to Jolokia and all is good